# Why does my code enter a locked area if the previous code has not released the lock?

Tags: android, thread-synchronization

My project has a button. When the button is pushed, it executes a function, `SimulateDataUpload`.
This SimulateDataUpload is locked with `lock.lock()`.
There is a for loop, packaged in a runnable, which updates a progress bar.
The onRun of the runnable also locks with `lock.lock()`.
When I click the button two times quickly, it's clear the for loop has not finished iterating, so the lock shouldn't be released. Why does the code enter the `SimulateDataUpload` again?

Code in MainActivity:

```
// defined before onCreate();
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

// defined in onCreate();
simulateDataUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       SimulateDataUpload();
    }
});


public void SimulateDataUpload()
{
    lock.lock();
    try 
    {
        Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
           + ". Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired.");
        Handler uiOperationsHandler = new Handler();
        setUiElements(true);

        Runnable simulateDataUploadRunnable = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                lock.lock();
                    try 
                    {
                         Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " 
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                            + ". Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock 
                            acquired.");
                        for (int i = 0; i < maxProgressBar + 1; i++) 
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } 
                            catch (InterruptedException e) 
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            int finalI = i;
                            uiOperationsHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " 
                                        + Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                                        + ". i: " + finalI 
                                        + ". Inside 
                                        uiOperationsHandler.post.");
                                    taskCompletedEventListener.
                                             getCallBackFunction().
                                             onTaskCompletedEvent(finalI == 
                                             maxProgressBar);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        lock.unlock();
                        Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " 
                            +Thread.currentThread().getName() 
                            +". lock released.");
                    }
            }
        };

        Thread simulateDataUploadThread = new 
            Thread(simulateDataUploadRunnable);
        simulateDataUploadThread.start();
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
        Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() 
           +". lock released.");
    }
}
```

Here is the normal output when button is only clicked once:

```
I/myTag: Thread name: main. Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-8. Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. lock released.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 0. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 1. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 2. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 3. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-8. lock released.
```

Here is the output when the button is clicked twice. I don't understand why I'm entering "Inside SimulateDataUpload..." a second time when it's clear the runnable with the locked object hasn't released the lock yet (hasn't finished its for loop iterations):

```
I/myTag: Thread name: main. Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. lock released.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-11. Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 0. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-11. lock released.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. lock released.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-12. Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock acquired.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 1. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 2. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 3. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 0. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 1. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 2. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-12. lock released.
I/myTag: Thread name: main. i: 3. Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.
```

Comment: because the same thread is holding the lock. as you can see in both of your logs, the thread holding the lock is `main`.

Comment: perhaps you should look into a `ReentrantLock` instead of using the synchronized keyword... do `sharedLock.lock()` before the try block, which will block until the lock is freed, do what you need in a try/finally block, and make sure to do`sharedLock.unlock()` in the finally part.

Comment: but if you look closer, the iterations are going in-order twice in a row. otherwise the ordering would be e.g 0,1,0,1,2,3,2,3. you have two consecutive 0-4 iterations.

Comment: Hi @Shark. I took your suggestion and used reentrantlock. More light has been shed on the problem, but I'm still not understanding the concept here. In the logs, you can see Thread-11 acquires the lock. Right when I press the button a second time, Thread-11 forcefully releases the lock, even though it's clear the for loop hasn't finished iterating. 

Why does Thread-11 prematurely release the lock when I click the button again? If you can answer that, and maybe give me a work around, I think most of my doubts will be cleared...

Comment: @Shark Ok, I got it to work. I just had to use                     
if(lock.isLocked()) 
{
   return;
}
But I'm still curious to my above question: For the given code, why does Thread-11 forcefully go to the unlock statement if a button is pressed a second time?

Comment: why do you have two `finally` blocks where the lock is released? do you really need this "lock, try doing work and unlock, but while doing work also try locking and unlock when finished" model?

Comment: also, i suggest you add some logging details to avoid having duplicate logs with different meaning... both your "lock aquired" and "lock released" logs are the same, when in fact they should be "lock acquired [OUTER]" and "lock acquired [INNER]" and similar for releasing the lock.

Comment: also, add logging for the `lockCount()` and see how many times your lock is being locked. of course, it should be 0 when starting the method and returning from it, but see whats there to see when one thread locked it twice (went in the inner runnable) and you click the button for the 2nd time. I still suspect it's only the `main` thread doing the locking, and thats why it's being allowed to lock again - because it still owns the lock.

Comment: My "lock aquired" and "lock released" are distinguished.
"I/myTag: Thread name: main. Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired." VS
"I/myTag: Thread name: Thread-8. Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock acquired."
You can see the thread names and function names are different.

You most certainly have more expertise on locks than I do. If you write an answer with some working code, I'll accept your answer, in case anyone else has the same question. In the mean time, I'll post what I've got working as an answer. As per your request, I'll update the log to show [OUTER] and [INNER]

Comment: i'm gonna be honest, i'm glad to help but can't actually bother to test it out so that i know my answer actually works alright. i'll let you answer your question and reap the 15 rep. if you can differentiate them - great. just have in mind - you also want to test it ***without having any logs*** because logs actually help hide race conditions as they have some other syncing mechanisms built into them. unit tests will help you catch race conditions better than logging. the order in which they appear in logcat also don't have to represent the real execution order either.

Answer (score 0):

due to logs `synchronised` keyword worked like a charm, you have created two `Thread`s and started them, never interrupted, no reference kept. second one must wait for ending execution of first as method/code is synchronised with same `final` object. so both `Thread`s will start but second one will execute in fact after first ends

Comment: I updated the solution. Please have a look at it. I can't understand why Thread-11 prematurely unlocks when I press the button a second time. I would think it would hold onto the lock, finish the iteration of its for loop, THEN release the lock. 
Any insight you can give would be great.

Comment: thats good question why first thread waits for all `post`s done when single click occur, and finishes earlier when another thread starts... sadly don't have idea, now curious tuu, upvoted question. btw. put log timings in question. maybe you should use `isLocked()` check before straight `lock()` call at the beginning of method. or `tryLock()` instead

Comment: add `catch` and check why `finally` gets called sooner, but still looks like whole loop executed properly, all 4 iteration logs are present... (maybe add to log name of calling `Thread`, not only executed)

Comment: i suggested using `lock()` and `unlock()` on purpose, because the `lock()` is blocking - it will wait until the lock is obtained and locked. using `tryLock()` is a non-blocking attempt of locking, and requires actually checking who holds the lock later on (before doing work). since we're talking about background threads here, they should all wait for each other, so `lock()` is the way to go imo.

Comment: have you checked with `catch` if any `Exception` happens there?

Answer (score 0):

Took @Shark suggestion and used a `reentrant lock`. Used the lock's `isLocked()` features to strengthen the solution.
Original code used `synchronized (lockObject)`. The separate thread was prematurely releasing the lock, so clicking on button multiple times would give strange results. If anyone can explain why it behaved that way, I'm definitely curious to know.

Anyway, here is the working solution:

```
//synchronize (myObject) doesn't work in this example... so using a ReentrantLock.
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final int maxProgressBar = 6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ... Other stuff defined here

    simulateDataUploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Problem: The user can click multiple times and our runnable will be concurrently run in multiple different threads
            // Used a lock to prevent this.

            // 1. SimulateDataUpload. Lock Acquired by Main Thread. A runnable package is created and a new thread with that package is started. Lock released by Main Thread.
            // 2. New thread runs and tries to acquire the lock, but is blocked until SimulateDataUpload releases the lock.
            // 3. The new Thread acquires the lock.
            // 4. The new Thread finishes the for loop and releases the lock.
            SimulateDataUpload();
        }
    });


}

public void SimulateDataUpload()
{
    if(lock.isLocked())
    {
        // If we are in the middle of an operation with the lock, return.
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        lock.lock();
    }
    try
    {
        Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". Inside SimulateDataUpload. lock acquired.");
        Handler uiOperationsHandler = new Handler();
        setUiElements(true);

        Runnable simulateDataUploadRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (lock.isLocked())
                {
                    // If we call this runnable with simulateDataUploadThread.start(), we need it to complete. So just wait for whatever has a lock to release the lock.
                }

                lock.lock();
                try
                {
                    Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". Inside runnable threadLockObject. lock acquired.");
                    for (int i = 0; i < maxProgressBar + 1; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " + "exception: " +e);
                        }

                        // Fire Event. Use a handler because we are going to be updating UI elements.
                        int finalI = i;
                        uiOperationsHandler.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". i: " + finalI + ". Inside uiOperationsHandler.post.");
                                taskCompletedEventListener.
                                        getCallBackFunction().
                                        onTaskCompletedEvent(finalI == maxProgressBar);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    lock.unlock();
                    Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() +". lock released.");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread simulateDataUploadThread = new Thread(simulateDataUploadRunnable);
        simulateDataUploadThread.start();
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
        Log.i("myTag", "Thread name: " +Thread.currentThread().getName() +". lock released.");
    }
}
```